# How to convert a char** based array from a C based dll to a c# equivalent?

Tags: c#, c, pinvoke

How can I convert a `char**` based array in C to an equivalent type in C#?

I have a DLL which has a function that takes a `char**` buffer and fills it with the right data.

I am using this DLL inside a C# application by using `DllImport`

The problem starts when I need to specify the `return type` or the `argument type` for such functions.

Which type in C# is an equivalent to C `char**` arrays?

What should I marshal and How?

**Update**:
This is my C function which resides inside my dll:

```
CDLL_API wchar_t** GetResults(wchar_t* word, int* length, int threshold = 9);
```

And these two function call the following function to get their value :

```
wchar_t** xGramManipulator::CGetNextWordsList(const wchar_t* currentWord, int threshold)
{
    wstring str(currentWord);
    auto result = GetNextWordsList(str, threshold);

    return GetCConvertedString(result);
}

wchar_t ** xGramManipulator::GetCConvertedString(vector< wstring> const &input)
{
    DisposeBuffers();//deallocates the previously allocated cStringArrayBuffer.
    cStringArraybuffer = new wchar_t*[input.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
    {
        cStringArraybuffer[i] = new wchar_t[input[i].size()+1];
        wcscpy_s(cStringArraybuffer[i], input[i].size() + 1, input[i].c_str());
        cStringArraySize++;
    }
    return cStringArraybuffer;
}
```

i used wchar_T** but i thought there shouldnt be any difference C# side ( since c# supports unicode by default! so if its different please address this too )

Comment: Have you tried to use ref string?

Comment: `string[]` should work afaik

Comment: no I am completely clueless about it.

Comment: what about wchar_t** does the same thing apply to it aswell?

Comment: can you show the c function definition from the header file? and its important to know if `**` should be a pointer array, or a pointer to a pointer, but from your question it seems its a string array

Comment: To get help with PInvoke, you need to provide native function declaration and small native code sample of this function call.

Comment: As well as what Alex says, you'll need to explain the structure of this `char**` object. Knowing the type is only part of the story.

Comment: Might be useful [Returning an Array of Strings from C++ to C# Part 1](http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/returning-an-array-of-strings-from-c-to-c-part-1/)

Comment: This is actually `IntPtr`, pointing to array of `IntPtr`s, each of them must be read by `Marshal.ReadIntPtr` method. Every `IntPtr` should be converted to string using `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` method. You also need to write unmanaged function, which releases this pointer, to prevent memory leak.

Comment: Also, `CGetNextWordsList` is buggy: members of `cStr` array are not initialized.

Comment: Why is this tagged C? The code is quite clearly C++.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:because its in a c based dll and there is a c wrapper involved.

Comment: There's still lots of unknowns here. The two functions are quite different. The first one has to allocate the arrays. The second one seems to expect the caller to allocate. But it's difficult to see how the second version could use that C++ method. If you could ask a better question, you'd get an answer.

Comment: Forget about the second one, if you can help me get the first one solved!I'll deal with the second one later.

Comment: Are you going to fix `xGramManipulator::CGetNextWordsList`? The thing is, if I show you how to call `GetResults`, then what will happen next is that your code will fail because `xGramManipulator::CGetNextWordsList` is totally broken. And then you'll not know whether the problem is with your code or mine.

Comment: @DavidHefferman:done i think it should be fine now.

Comment: GetResults function doesn't contain information about allocated array size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In comments you state that you are most interested in dealing with this function:

```
CDLL_API wchar_t** GetResults(wchar_t* word, int threshold);
```

You cannot expect the p/invoke marshaller to marshal the return value for you. You'll need to do that by hand. What's more, you cannot reliably call the function as it is currently designed. That's because the caller has no way of obtaining the length of the returned array. You'll need to add an extra parameter to return the array length to the caller:

```
CDLL_API wchar_t** GetResults(wchar_t* word, int threshold, int* len);
```

On the C# side you'd declare it like this:

```
[DllImport(@"DllName.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern IntPtr GetResults(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string word,
    int threshold,
    out int len
);
```

And you'll need to make sure that the calling convention you specify in your `DllImport` matches that of the native code. I'm assuming `cdecl`, but only you know for sure.

Call it like this:

```
int len;
IntPtr results = GetResults(word, threshold, out len);
IntPtr[] ptrs = new IntPtr[len];
Marshal.Copy(results, ptrs, 0, len);
for (int i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    string item = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(ptrs[i]);
}
```

To avoid a memory leak you'll need to export another function that deallocates the memory allocated by `GetResults`. Call that once you have finished calling `PtrToStringUni`.

Quite frankly this looks very much like it would be more suited to a mixed mode C++/CLI solution.

Comment: Thanks i'll give a try and if i faced any issues i'll comment .Thanks again for everything :)

Comment: @Hossein Yes, silly me, should be `IntPtr[] ptrs`, as per latest update

Comment: Also, you transcribed the parameters to `Marshal.Copy` in the wrong order.